2021 Bitcoin recover funds sid to be in Binace wallet without my permission
Need help recovering Bitcoin from 2021. ledger document sent to me via email and link to transfer and withdraw funds. Large deposits recorded from 2021-2024. I was told to withdraw funds or they would be returned because of non -activity. I paid for the transfer processing, watched the funds being transferred and became suspicious. tried to stop process, one completed and process began over again. At one point it read that my bitcoin was in a Binance wallet...I contacted Binance o see if my funds were in a wallet and somehow they started me a new account saying I didnt have account or a wallet transfer. Just need to. know how to get my bitcoin deposits that I saw only a few days ago. please help!
